# Closest equivalent of dstat on mac

Tags: statistics

It seems that only `iostat` were available on mac. But I am looking for more comprehensive set of stats including cpu, memory, and network.  What are the options here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though this is old, time travelers might find Dabz `dstat` fork/port useful.  See:

- https://lamada.eu/blog/2016/02/12/adapting-dstat-on-mac/
- https://github.com/Dabz/dstat/tree/mac

dstat is a Python script. The *Makefile* file has to be adjusted slightly to install to macOS (e.g. the `install -D...` switch doesn't exist in the default macOS *install* bin) - there is nothing to compile though. Additionally it's recommended to install brew/python2 and a separate Python env to install additional required packages with pip.

A lot of stats don't work though because they rely on Linux paths (e.g. /proc).

Comment: Did you look at it? The `Makefile` references `rpmbuild` unconditionally. Does not sound like a `Darwin` platform to me..

Comment: OK I'll accept this as "the closest we can get"

Answer (score 4):

> Dstat is a versatile replacement for vmstat, iostat and ifstat. Dstat
>   overcomes some of the limitations and adds some extra features.

As you said, `iostat` is available on macs. But, additionally you can install `ifstat` using [homebrew](http://brew.sh) by typing the following:

```
brew install ifstat
```

To install homebrew -if you haven't it yet-, just use the following command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: Turns out I really need dstat- and not something else.. I do charts for demos off of it.  Big big hole in the mac offering.